# How to use exec function in PHP to run commands in backend?

Tags: php, curl, exec

I am using below curl command. exec() function is taking around 60 ms to execute which caused high response time.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --connect-timeout 1 -m 1 -d '<payload>' '<url>' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: maybe the request it self couses high response time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc_open` function instead of `exec` function. Also you can check what cause a problem in term of performance by printing in log file.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
array('file', 'response.log', 'a'), // stdout
array('pipe', 'w'), // stderr
);

$env = array(
'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin' //Path to node bin dir
);

$proc = proc_open('wget -qO- --post-data "{YOUR POST DATA}" "{URL}" &', $descriptorspec, $pipes, __DIR__, $env);

if (is_resource($proc))
{
proc_close($proc);
}

**Example:**
$proc = proc_open('wget -qO- --post-data "id=' . $_POST["id"] . '" "http://www.example.com" &', $descriptorspec, $pipes, __DIR__, $env);
```